Where can I see when a Slack profile got deactivated?
I wonder the following: where can I see when a Slack profile in a given Slack workspace got deactivated?

Reddit user edvanilla replied the following:

If you don't have admin permissions - then you can't check that. If you have - billing or logs.

Reddit user Training-Flan8092 mentioned the following approximation:

If don’t have admin and the user was active you could @[user] in search and see when the last time they sent a message/comment.

